# Different number of Vertices, Faces and Triangles between object mode and edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, objects, vertices

In object mode it says that I have 1 of 99 objects selected and over 10000 Vertices, 2000 Faces, and a similar high number for Tris. When I tab into edit mode it shows the actual numbers of the object, 28 Faces, 100 or so Vertices etc. It is the only object that I have, I see nothing else. I have no idea what the cause is, when I delete said object everything goes to 0 again. So it doesn't appear to be extra objects that I'm missing. What would cause this?

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the object? That would cause the difference you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you may have a modifier on the object that does not affect the mesh during edit mode, but the changes are shown in object mode.